# Подгрузить страницу в flash ролик

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, adobe, adobe-air

Здравствуйте! Я использую для создания флеш-роликов FlashDevelop (но это не важно, могу и в другом пописать, если будет решение) . Мне необходимо на пару секунд отобразить в ролике web-страницу. Можно ли это как-то сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если целевая среда Adobe AIR, то можно воспользоваться этим:
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html

Если в качестве среды будет FlashPlayer, то:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/htmlwrapper/